# Fetch subsets from collections in backbone.js via rest

Tags: rest, backbone.js, collections

Currently i am working on a single-page-application with backbone.js.

My server is providing a REST api.

`http://server.com/article` is returning the latest articles from all categories.

`http://server.com/article/categoryname` is returning the latest articles from specified category only.

My current collection looks like this:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/article'], function(Backbone, Article) {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Article,
        url: "http://server.com/article", 
    });
});
```

So with `fetch` i can receive all the latest articles from all categories. Where should i implement my specific category requests, so i do not have to create a collection for every category by myself and a possible caching won't be so difficult at all.

Would it be better to change my rest api and receive all articles and filter them in the backbone app? Or should i implement a fetchFromCategory method in my collection and build the caching myself?

I am thankful for every hint or idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fetching all the `Articles` in a single request is not an issue, you can do that. To get `articles` by `categoryName`, you can then add a method in the collection as below :

```
define(['backbone', 'models/article'], function(Backbone, Article) {
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Article,
        url: "http://server.com/article",
        getArticlesByCategory : function(category) {
            return this.filter(function(article){
                    //Assuming 'Article' has a property named 'categoryName'
                    return article.get('categoryName') == category;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now, if `articles` is your `collection` you can do :

```
var categoryXYZArticles = articles.getArticlesByCategory('XYZ');
```

Comment: Ok great. What if i only fetched the first 20 articles from all categories and try to select the first 10 from category business. Is there is a simple way that the collection fetches the next articles until 10 articles from categor business exist or do i have to do this by myself? A yes or no is totally fine :)

Comment: NO. Unless you do `collection.fetch()` request will never be sent to server. You will have to add some logic yourself.